# authlogic authentication fails after moving site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, authlogic

I used pgbackups to restore the old site DB to the new site, all the user records are there but if you try to login now, you will receive and error that your "username/password" is incorrect. Is there something I'm missing? This seems like it should just work. the secret_key_base was carried over with the same value

### backstory

A contractor built a website for us using RoR and hosted it on heroku.  We have now taken over maintaining the site. They sent us the code and I configured it on a new heroku account as new heroku app.

Comment: No, I think it has something to with the crypted password and some hash or salt.

Comment: You probably have something like this in your sessions controller: if user && user.authenticate(session_params[:password]). Check which condition fails